# Law of Sines Trig Problem

Tags: trigonometry

I'm experiencing a problem solving for an angle of a triangle using the law sines.

So I know the Angle $120$ degrees, the opposite of which is $13$. I know the opposite of the unknown angle which is $7$.

$$\frac{Sin(120)}{13}=\frac{Sin(A)}{7}$$
$$\frac{7*Sin(120)}{13}=Sin(A)$$
$$arcsin(\frac{7*Sin(120)}{13})=A$$
Why does this give me the wrong answer ~$64,62$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us what you did after the last step.

Comment: typed in $sin^{-1}(sin120/13*7$ in my calculator...

Comment: Your answer 64.62 is for $\sin^{-1}(\sin(120/13*7))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin 120$ degrees $\approx 0.866$

$(0.866*7)/13 \approx 0.4663$

$\sin^{-1}(0.4663)\approx 27.795$

*The mistake you are probably making is that you are not putting parenthesis correctly around your expression*.

$\cfrac{\sin 120}{13*7}\ne \cfrac{\sin 120*7}{13}$

For example: $\sin^{-1} 12+1 \ne \sin^{-1} (12+1)$

Or, maybe it is doing $\sin \left(\cfrac{120}{13}\right)$ instead of $\cfrac{\sin (120)}{13}$.

Comment: Weird, why won't it give me the correct answer doing $sin^{-1}(7*(sin120/13))$

Comment: Are you sure that you are typing it correctly?

Comment: @user472288 Maybe it is doing $\sin (120/13)$ instead of $\sin (120)/13$

Comment: You were right, it was the parentheses. What I did was $arcsin(7*sin(120/13$ instead of $arcsin(7*sin(120)/13$

Comment: @user472288 Glad to help!

Comment: Huh. Looks like this was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Let check that the calculator is taking degrees and not radians for 120.

To check verify that you obtain $\sin (120) = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

Comment: Actually I should obtain (in degrees) 27.79 because that is the correct answer which i'm not getting.

Comment: Try to calculate sin 120 and let me know the result.

Comment: It's $0.8660$, I know it's in degrees.

Comment: Then it should be an error with computing, try again calculating separately each term.

Comment: Yeah it was, I misplaced a parentheses the whole time. Thanks :).

Comment: Well done I was afraid that arcsin didn’t work anymore!

Comment: I was about to throw that calculator all the way back to amazon headquarters. :) Cheers mate, thanks for your input.